# im confused on how to create a class on c++

Tags: c++

How do I create a class that that will get the users information about the best route to take based on the time they want to leave once the user inputs three routes, 3 departure times and 3 arrival times

I've tried the code below but I am stuck right now .I know, I have to make some if statements probably..

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class route {
private:
    std::string name_;
    int departure_time_;
    int arrival_time_;
public:
    void set_name(std::string name) {
        name_ = name;
    }
    void set_departure_time(int deparure_time) {
        departure_time_ = deparure_time;
    }
    void set_arrival_time(int arrival_time) {
        arrival_time_ = arrival_time;
    }
};
void route1 () {
    std::string name;
    int departure;
    int arrival;
    std::cout << "Route 1:\n";
    std::cout << "Please enter the name of the route: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    std::cout << "Please enter the departure time of the route: ";
    std::cin >> departure;
    std::cout << "Please enter the arrival time of the route: ";
    std::cin >> arrival;

}
void route2 () {
    std::string name;
    int departure;
    int arrival;
    std::cout << "Route 2:\n";
    std::cout << "Please enter the name of the route: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    std::cout << "Please enter the departure time of the route: ";
    std::cin >> departure;
    std::cout << "Please enter the arrival time of the route: ";
    std::cin >> arrival;

}
void route3() {
    std::string name;
    int departure;
    int arrival;
    std::cout << "Route 3:\n";
    std::cout << "Please enter the name of the route: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    std::cout << "Please enter the departure time of the route: ";
    std::cin >> departure;
    std::cout << "Please enter the arrival time of the route: ";
    std::cin >> arrival;

}
int main() {
    int time_leaving;
    std::cout << "Welcome to TuffyTravel!\n";
    route1();
    std::cin.ignore();
    route2();
    std::cin.ignore();
    route3();
    std::cout << "Please enter the time you wish to leave: ";
    std::cin >> time_leaving;
}
```

The result should give the best route based on the time they want to leave

Comment: Do you **need** to place all this in a class?  This may be best implemented using free standing functions. There are many existing algorithms on the internet for finding the shortest path.  Search for "c++ find shortest path route".

Comment: If you want other people to read your code, it's vital you learn how to indent it in a conventional way.

Answer (score 0):

This might be some of the code you're looking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Route {
  std::string name;
  int departure_time;
  int arrival_time;
};

Route get_route (std::string prompt) {
  Route route;
  std::cout << prompt << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Please enter the name of the route: ";
  std::cin >> route.name;
  std::cout << "Please enter the departure time of the route: ";
  std::cin >> route.departure_time;
  std::cout << "Please enter the arrival time of the route: ";
  std::cin >> route.arrival_time;
  return route;
}

int main() {
  int time_leaving;
  std::cout << "Welcome to TuffyTravel!\n";
  Route route1 = get_route("Route 1");
  Route route2 = get_route("Route 2");
  Route route3 = get_route("Route 3");
  std::cout << "Please enter the time you wish to leave: ";
  std::cin >> time_leaving;

  std::vector<Route> routes_vec { route1, route2, route3 };

  // Now find the best route in routes_vec

  return 0;
}
```

Note that it does not find the best route in `routes_vec` nor does it perform any error handling in case the user enters something that is not a number for departure or arrival time.